# How to run the official vue.js examples?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I git cloned vue, cd'ed into one of the examples folder and ran `npm install`. Everything went fine, then I ran `npm run dev` and it gets stuck at this stage. Is there anything else I should do to run this locally?

```
npm run dev
> vue@2.4.2 dev /vue
> rollup -w -c build/config.js --environment TARGET:web-full-dev

bundling...
bundled in 2456ms. Watching for changes...
```

Comment: Navigate to localhost:8080, it should be working

Comment: I get a 404. That's why I asked

Comment: You can open just html file in your browser, there no need server. In examples folder already builded files.

Comment: It's watching for changes like it says, AFAIK, vue doesn't include any web server for you

Comment: Why did you clone vue instead of just installing vue-cli? CLI comes with an express server.

Comment: I wanted to try running the examples locally. Should I have done something differently?

Comment: Well if your goal is to just run the examples locally for the sake of trying it out you can just import a pre-bundled hosted version of vue (like this one https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2) as a script into a new html file and copy the example into it and it should run by opening it with the browser. If you actually want to create a new project from scratch though I highly recommend you use vue-cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to run a local web server.**

Try this:

Install `http-server` package with npm:

```
$ sudo npm install -g http-server
```

Run it in the root of the vue cloned folder:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:vuejs/vue.git
$ cd vue
$ http-server -o -c .
```

In yout browser, navigate to the examples folder, **for instance**:

http://127.0.0.1:8081/examples/select2/

They are the same from here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that was all I needed to do. When generating vue-cli projects `npm run dev` runs the server for me 

Comment: That's because vue-cli generates templates for a complete project... "Examples" is a simpler simpler simpler project to show how Vue is powerful.